# How to move to next line while reading/writing a file in C++

Tags: c++

I want to know how to move to the next line while reading or writing a file in C++. I tried to move from one line to another using seekp but it just moved one character space ahead in the same line.

```
ofstream writer; 
ifstream reader;
int loop;
string test;

writer.open("SU.txt");

cout << "Enter String 1" << endl;
getline(cin, test);
writer.seekp(0);
writer << test;

cout << "Enter String 2" << endl;
getline(cin, test);
writer.seekp(1);
writer << test;

cout << "Enter String 3" << endl;
getline(cin, test);
writer.seekp(2);
writer << test;

cout << "Writer Complete!" << endl;
writer.close();

reader.open("SU.text");
for (loop = 0; loop <= 2; loop++) {
    reader >> test;
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

If I enter the following strings as my input,

```
Hello

Welcome

Goodbye
```

The output I would get in that file would be,

```
HWGoodbye
```

So I would like to know how move from one line to another while reading or writing a file. Thank you!

Comment: what do you think `endl` does in your `cout`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `seek` the `writer` `ofstream` after each write, just add a `std::endl` at end of each write and that's all, i.e.:

```
cout << "Enter String 1" << endl;
getline(cin, test);
writer << test << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! but I how can I move the to a specific line while writing to a file? Also using endl does not work while reading from a file. How do I move to another line while reading from a file?